# PHP list() -- explode() offset error

Tags: php, codeigniter

Racking my brain on why this is returning PHP Error: Undefined offset: 1

```
public function index($hash)
    {   
        //$hash = 44253_13456789
        list($part1,$part2) = explode('_', $hash);

        $id = $part1;

        $tpl_data = array('id' => $id );
        $this->load->view('main/index', $tpl_data);
    }
```

the error is happening on the list() = explode(); Thanks for any insight on this.

Here is the URL for the error. http://www.onlinealbumproofing.com/beta/ipad/index/44253_1368207168

**UPDATED:**

Here is the controller code.

```
echo $hash;

list($part1,$part2) = explode('_', $hash);

$id = $part1;

$tpl_data = array('id' => $id );
$this->load->view('ipad/index', $tpl_data);
```

**Updated Again....**
OK, so looks like the error is happening on the ajax request

```
var id = $('body').attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ipad/loadImages',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {id: id},
        success: function(json, textStatus, xhr) {
            for (var i = 0; i < json.images.length; i++) {

                //do something
            }
        }, error: function(json, textStatus) {
            console.log(textStatus);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you 1000% sure the value of `$hash` is "44253_13456789"? Then this should not happen!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is explode() seems like to return only one value.

list() is trying to do :

```
 $tmp = explode("_", $hash);
 $part1 = $tmp[0];
 $part2 = $tmp[1]; //Here is your undefined offset.
```

Doublecheck your $hash value.

Comment: Looks like the error is happening on the ajax request, not sure why the index function is even called again....

Answer (score 0):

`list($part1,$part2)` requires the array has two elements at least.

If `$hash` doesn't has a `_` in it, then `explode('_', $hash)` won't return an array with two elements.

Comment: That won't throw an offset error though, $part2 would simply be null

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you do not have `2` tokens being returned from your explode function.  Which means you need to check the input to ensure that you will get the 2 tokens you require.